# Python-telegram - is it possible to get the number of messages sent by a user in a group?

Tags: python, telegram

Is it possible to retrieve how many messages has a user sent in a Telegram group using `python-telegram-bot` or any other tool to create telegram bots using python?

The closest i found is [get_chat_member](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.get_chat_member), which is very useful but it only lacks the info i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way a bot is able to receive messages is via their [`getUpdates`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates) method. (Implemented either via webhooks or polling).

This means, in order to count messages in any way at all, the bot has to be active in the group and be able to listen in to messages. You cannot get past sent messages, thus you have to keep track of the counts yourself.

Also see [*What messages will my bot get*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get) as there are limitations for groups where privacy mode is enabled.

---

Note: This answer is applicable regardless of the library used to implement the bot. To implement this feature, you will need to find out how to receive messages for your specific library.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was hoping there was a built in method. Basically i need to count if a member has sent more than 10 messages in order to assign a "new member" / "normal member" status, and having to count every message with a database is a big problem since it's a db query for every message

Comment: @JayK23 while unrelated to the question: There are some "optimizations* you can do in that regard, for example using a technique called "debouncing" to reduce the amount of queries performed when lots of messages come in quickly. Also when dealing with high data volumes, batching inserts may also be useful especially when considering that inserts could get expensive when you add indexes for the query you describe.

Comment: Thank you again! This is a great advice and i didn't think about it. I was actually thinking of using Redis for this, so that i can keep everything in memory

Comment: @JayK23 perfectly valid as well, just don't forget to consider the need for persistence depending on your use-case ;)